# MacBook Pro can't see my android phone WiFi hotspot

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, network, wifi, android

My MacBook Pro pro can't see my Android phone wifi hotspot, when I got the phone new the MacBook was seeing the hotspot and I was connecting to it but after some months it stopped seeing the network. It sees other wifi network around but can't see that of my Android phone

It also happened with my Fujitsu Laptop running Windows 10, sometime ago and I was able to solve the issue by resetting my network.

I have tried disabling my network and putting it up again by doing ( sudo ifconfig en0 down ) on the Terminal but it still did not work, I tried disabling the wifi by going to System preferences ->> Network ->> select the wifi from the left hand bar ->> and clicking on ( - "Delete the selected service") and used the ( + "Create a new service") to add it again but it still did not work.

Comment: Your question presumes the fault is with your MacBook Pro. Instead, the fault may be with your Android phone. Can other computers or devices see and connect to the Android wifi hotspot?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes other phones and laptops can see and connect to the network and the mac can also see some other networks around... my Fujitsu running Windows 10 also do have that same issue once in a while and i fix it by resetting the network

Answer (score 2):

Same issue, I changed my Android hotspot settings to the 5GHz band and to WPA3 Personal, but the issue was that **I had an extra blank space in my password.**

Comment: 5ghz and wpa3 personal solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Bluetooth PAN? Turn on your hotspot and open bluetooth settings on both your Mac and phone. You should be able to see your phone show up and pair with it.

Comment: I have been using Bluetooth to connect to the internet but it still doesn't fix the Wifi issue that am having

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but was able to fix this by switching the hotspot wifi network on my android phone to 5GHz Band, it can be done deep in the hotspot settings, see also this article: https://www.doncaprio.com/having-trouble-connecting-with-android-7-0-wireless-hotspot-try-this/

Comment: I have tried switching to 5GHz  but my mobile phone only has 2.5GHz